# Responsive email template android 2.3.6

Tags: css, responsive-design, media-queries, email-templates

I am reading on the internet, that responsive email templates are supported since Android version 2.3. I am the owner of a Samsung Galaxy Advance, which runs Android 2.3.6. This device sadly doesn't seem to support any kind of CSS at all in a mail template.

Does anyone know if there's a setting which must be turned on? I've tried the nave Gmail and Email apps, but neither of them show emails the way they show on an iPhone for example.

If there's a solution for it, I'd like to hear it.

Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 0):

Gmail doesn't support media queries. Try reading on your native email app via a different domain. (hook up you@somewheredifferent.com) I had issues with my work email - the corporate Microsoft Exchange (or some security software they have) was stripping the media queries out. When sending to me@myownsite.com it came through perfectly.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, if there is no style tag, then media queries won't be applied. And that is the case with gmail and with some other e-mail clients. If you build the mobile version first and create the media queries to recreate the desktop version, then it will be cool on every mobile devices.
The drawback of this is when you open the mail on a desktop client, which does not support the style tag (so the media queries) then you will see the mobile version on desktop.

If you are looking for a template which does the work for you, then I recomment Antwort. This is a three column layout, working in a way what I mentioned before. (http://internations.github.io/antwort/)

If you are looking for a tool, then I recomment you this: www.edmdesigner.com - although the beta phase has not started yet.